# Android game, playing "Game Over" sound FX

Tags: java, android, game-development, soundpool

I am writing a simple Android game. I have trouble in playing a simple "game complete" sound effect, as soon as the game is finished (either won or lost), before there is the option to start a new game.

My source code is:

```
soundPool.play(complete, 1,1, 0, 0, 1);
soundPool.autoPause();
```

If I don't use `autoPause()` the background music continues to loop, and I don't want that in the "Game Over" screen. As it is now, the "complete" sound doesn't play properly.

Any idea or help, etc. would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stop the background music, and get rid of autoPause.

Let's assume you started the background music loop like this:

```
int bg_music_loop = soundPool.play(BACKGROUND_MUSIC_ID, volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f);
```

Then you'd stop it using

```
soudPool.stop(bg_music_loop);
```

And then you can start your game-over sound:

```
soundPool.play(complete, 1,1, 0, 0, 1);
```

Comment: Thank you, but for some reason it doesn't work properly, although the game compiles without errors. I tried a couple of times, but either the "complete" sound plays in a strange way, or the "bg_music_loop" doesn't stop.

Comment: what do you mean "plays in a strange way" ?

Comment: Sound plays very differently from the original. Perhaps the problem is with soundPool and background music. I read that soundPool is not the best tool for that.

Comment: I am also trying with a new soundPool, but for some reason it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you try a different sound file for the "game-over" ? Maybe it's broken, or the file format is causing the problems. If you want to end the 1st soundpool, try `.Release()`

Comment: Sure, i'll make these tests, and get back with the results. Anyway, these are all .ogg files.

Comment: I just read that soundPool.stop() accepts the sound's streamID as an argument, an Int returned by the load() method, but how do I know what is it?

Comment: Update: it works nicely when the background music isn't looping. If it is looping,  soundPool.stop(streamID) is not stopping, in my case. I assigned int streamID = soundPool.play(bg_sound, etc), but it doesn't stop.

Comment: you can try `.stop(background_id)` - if that doesn't help: set maxStreams to 1.

Comment: It works now with maxStreams no longer to the default 10, but to the number of sounds required, in my case 4. So thanks again.

Comment: Is there the possibility of disabling a sound effect that is not currently playing, too? For example, in the "Game Over" screen, I'd like to silence the "collision" effects, but not others.

Comment: Yes, you should store the id when you start the sound like `collision_id = soundPool.play(COLLISION_SOUND_ID, v, v , 1,0, 1);` and then you can stop it using `soundPool.stop(collision_id);`

Comment: I tried: int newstreamID = soundPool.play(COLLISION_SOUND_ID, v, v , 1,0, 1); and then: soundPool.stop(newstreamID); but it doesn't seem to disable a sound effect that is not looping, or currently playing.

Comment: yes, the SoundPool can only handle sounds that are currently in the pool (e.g. playing). If you don't the collision to play in game-over mode, then you should not call `play()`. Something like `if(!gameOver) { soundPool.play(COLLISION.....) }`. Just set a variable called `gameOver` to false once the game ends.

Comment: I'll try, although I don't want to further complicate the game logic...

Comment: PS: I just tried soundPool.unload(collision_sound) and it works, but the the sound doen't play in the new game either... is there a way back from unload()?